# I wonder where mariadb is installed in centOS

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, centos

I searched for the location of mariadb installation through googling, but I couldn't find it because it only showed how to install or set it up. I wonder where mariadb is installed in centOS. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me.

Comment: what make you think its installed. Does `yum list installed` show it?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this command you will get list of all files in the package:

```
rpm -ql mariaddb....
```